# Multiple Nested Classes Java

Tags: java, class

Hi so I have a class that has mulitple layers of nested classes within it and I was wondering why it does not work. For some reason I cant create a new StackNode I was wondering why that might be.

```
public class MultiStack {
    Stack1[] arr;
    int lim,numplate,index;

    MultiStack(int limit, int total) {
        lim = limit;
        numplate = total;
        int ssize =0;
        if(total%lim==0) {
            ssize = total/lim;
        } else {
            ssize = (total/lim) +1;
        }
        arr = new Stack1[ssize];
    }

    class Stack1 {
        StackNode top;
        int size;

        class StackNode{
            StackNode next;
            int value;
        }
    }
    public void push(int value){
        if(arr[index].size < lim) {
            push1(index);
        }
    }
    public void push1(int index) {
        arr[index].size++;
        StackNode cur = new StackNode(); //here is my issue
        cur.next = arr[index].top;
        arr[index].top = cur;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "does not work"?

Comment: Also, are you aware of [`static`-ness of inner classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70324)?

Comment: it doesnt allow me to create a new StackNode()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither class `Stack1` nor class `StackNode` are *static*.

Therefore you need an instance of the surrounding class to instantiate it.

When you try to instantiate class `StackNode` you are in an object of `MultiStack`:

```
public void push1(int index) {
    arr[index].size++;
    Stack1.StackNode cur = new Stack1().new StackNode(); // here is my issue
    cur.next = arr[index].top;
    arr[index].top = cur;
}
```